# Google Sheets - How do multiply a SUM?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, sum, formula

Google Sheets is driving me insane
[image]

If I SUM up numbers from only one column and multiply by 2, I get 8, which is right:

```
=SUM(A:A)*2
```

But when I add numbers from Column B like so, I get 6 as the answer, where I should be getting 14.

```
=SUM((A:A)*2,B:B)
```

Can someone explain to me what's wrong with my formula?

Answer (score 2):

Try enclosing the function in an arrayformula.

```
=arrayformula(SUM((A:A)*2,B:B))
```

Edit:

Realized you were looking for an explanation. In the first example you are summing a range then multiplying that number. The second set has an array function and it works like

sum(2*[1,1,1],[1,2,2,1])

The first array doesn't resolve properly and you get the sum of the second. By enclosing the command withing an arrayformula command, it knows that you are performing matrix math.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to nest `SUM` functions, but are missing one. How about the following:

```
=SUM(SUM(A:A)*2,B:B)
```

where the inside `SUM` is used as the first parameter for the outside `SUM`.

[image]